# Swapfile not being used and read-error crashes Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: swap, crash

After making my swapfile large enough to finally make my hibernation run I noticed it was barely used no matter how much swapiness I set. I didn't think anything of it. Fast forward half a year and for no reason in particular the swapfile started acting up.
My computer would freeze shortly and soon completely crash, displaying such error messages:
[image]

It has happened on multiple occasions now. Lately I've been using a lot of RAM (~25 Chrome tabs and multiple VLC players open), but not more than what I used to do before. I tried recreating the swapfile but to no avail. What do I do?

My RAM is 7.5 GB, swap 8 GB. What other relevant info could be helpful?
[image]

Comment: How did you make the swap file? What are the permissions on it?

Comment: @Matigo I believe I used a tutorial very similar to [this one](https://linuxize.com/post/create-a-linux-swap-file/) so the permission should be correct. I checked it and it was set to "owner (=root): write and read, everyone else : nothing"

Comment: Hmm ... if the permissions are `-rw-------` and `root:root`, the only thing that would really jump out would be not having first used `fallocate` when creating the swapfile. For testing purposes, could you increase swappiness to something excessive, like 80? `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=80`. This will force writes to the swap much sooner. Check if there are any error messages in `/var/log/syslog` as the system tries to use the storage space.

Comment: @Matigo I set my swappiness to 0, RAM was at ~75 % of my 7.5 GB. Then at exactly 14:56 I changed swappiness to 100. No swap is being used, but the logs seem devoid of errors, as you can see [here](https://ctxt.io/2/AACgirS3FQ)

Permissions are exactly 
`-rw------- 1 root root 8589934592 led 11 09:20 /swapfile`.